# JSF custom component: support for arguments of custom types, the attribute setter is never invoked

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, attributes, custom-component

I've created my custom **JSF** component according to one of many tutorials (I'm using **PrimeFaces**), I've added an argument which was successfully passed to component.

```html
<c:custom command="command"/>
```

```java
public void setCommand(String command) {
    log.debug("setCommand {}", command);
    this.command = command;
}
```

But I need the argument of custom type, and that's something that I couldn't find in tutorials, which are handling only the most trivial cases.

```html
<c:custom image="#{currentImageBean.image}"/>
```

```java
public void setImage(Object image) {
    log.debug("setImage {}", image);
    this.image = (Image) image;
}
```

The bean is returning the object of type **Image**, but the setter is not called. I've expected that this will work, because otherwise a good tutorial should mention that case, but now I'm stuck with the worse of the errors: nothing happens, and there's nothing in logs suggesting why... So, what is wrong, what I need to change, where to look for potential error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with custom types. This has to do with using literal (static) values versus EL as in `attributename="attributevalue"` versus `attributename="#{attribute.value}"`.

This behavior is expected and by specification. Attribute values which are EL expressions ([`ValueExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html)s) are been set by [`UIComponent#setValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression%28java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression%29). They are namely supposed to be evaluated only when they are *really* been requested, usually during view render time. They shouldn't be evaluated *directly* during baking the `UIComponent` instance as that would defeat the nature of dynamic value expressions (think of depending on the current iteration round of data table).

Better is to delegate the getters/setters of attributes which can hold an EL value expression to [`UIComponent#getStateHelper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper%28%29) instead of to local properties. The `setValueExpression()` will namely ultimately also end up in the `StateHelper`. The [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) also resolves the values from the [`StateHelper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHelper.html).

```
public Image getImage() {
   return (Image) getStateHelper().eval("image");
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
    getStateHelper().put("image", image);
}
```

Note that there's no local property. So when you need the (evaluated) value of the attribute, then just call the getter.

In order to achieve your initial functional requirement, which is the logging of the set attribute, you might want to add the logging statement to the `setValueExpression()` override which delegates to `super`.

```
@Override
public void setValueExpression(String name, ValueExpression binding) {
    log.debug(....);
    super.setValueExpression(name, binding);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have this object under getAttributes.get("image");

Comment: You're welcome. That's correct, it's as answered also available by `getAttributes()`. I however strongly recommend to change the getter/setter as such and then use them directly. This is also how JSF implementations and component libraries build their components.