# JSF2 custom component (UIInput) 'value' attribute

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component

Hi I'm trying to create a custom component that extends `UIInput`. In that component I generate one html input, one html submit button and one line of text. The codes are as below:

```
@Override
public void decode(FacesContext context) {
    Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String clientId = getClientId(context);
    char sep = UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context);
    String symbol = ((String) requestMap.get(clientId + sep + "inputfield"));
    setSubmittedValue(symbol);
}

@Override
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    String clientId = getClientId(context);
    char sep = UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context);
    //-----------------------this generates an html input-------------------------
    encodeInputField(context, clientId + sep + "inputfield");
    //Now if I uncomment the next line it generates another html, whose value always stays the same as the first one
    //encodeInputField(context, clientId + sep + "inputfield2");
    encodeSubmitButton(context, clientId + sep + "submit");
    encodeOutputField(context);
}

private void encodeInputField(FacesContext context, String clientId) throws IOException {
    // Render a standard HTML input field
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.startElement("input", this);
    writer.writeAttribute("type", "text", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, "clientId");
    Object value = getValue();
    if (value != null) {
        writer.writeAttribute("value", value.toString(), "value");
    }
    writer.writeAttribute("size", "6", null);
    writer.endElement("input");
}

private void encodeSubmitButton(FacesContext context, String clientId) throws IOException {
    // render a submit button
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    writer.startElement("input", this);
    writer.writeAttribute("type", "Submit", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, "clientId");
    writer.writeAttribute("value", "Click Me!", null);
    writer.endElement("input");
}

private void encodeOutputField(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    //----------------weird value that comes out of nowhere-----------------------
    String hellomsg = (String) getAttributes().get("value");
    writer.startElement("p", this);
    writer.writeText("You entered: " + hellomsg, null);
    writer.endElement("p");
}
```

Now everything works fine but I don't understand where the `value` attribute in `String hellomsg = (String) getAttributes().get("value");` comes. I tried to debug this program and the `getAttributes()` hashmap also contains weird entries and I couldn't find any entry whose key is `"value"`.

Finally if I generate two html input then the second input's value always stays the same as the first one.

I also noticed that I can include a `value` in the tag, e.g. `<mycc:cinput value="yes">` and when the page loads, the value of the html input generated is set to `yes`.

My doubt is: is every UIInput has a default `value` attribute? If so, is that attribute value always linked to whatever html input's `value` attribute? If so, is it always linked to the `value` attribute of the first html input generated?

Thanks in advance for reading such a long question. If possible can you guys let me know where I can find answers to issues like this? Im getting a headache browsing random google search results@_@

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Now everything works fine but I don't understand where the value attribute in String hellomsg = (String) getAttributes().get("value"); comes. I tried to debug this program and the getAttributes() hashmap also contains weird entries and I couldn't find any entry whose key is "value".*

Read the [javadoc of `UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29). To the point, it's really an abstract map. The `get("value")` doesn't really return an entry from the map, but it basically obtains the `value` property of the component itself by invoking its `getValue()` method, if any available (and it is, in case of `UIInput`). But if you're already sitting in the component itself, you don't need to invoke `getAttributes().get("value")`, you can just invoke the `getValue()` method directly.

Note thus that if you intend to put a custom attribute in the attribute map, then you should be using a different name, or, better, to make use of `StateHelper`.

#### See also:

- [JSF custom component: support for arguments of custom types, the attribute setter is never invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491805/jsf-custom-component-support-for-arguments-of-custom-types-the-attribute-sette)
- [How to save state when extending UIComponentBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405278/how-to-save-state-when-extending-uicomponentbase)